# PHP setcookie function not honoring httponly or secure arguments

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, httponly, hsts

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

I can run this:

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 1, time()+86400*365*2, "/", ".domain.com", false, false);
```

And I get this in the response headers when I load the script:

```
cookie_name=1; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2021 19:08:57 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; path=/; domain=.domain.com;HttpOnly;Secure
```

As you can see, its forcing the flags for httponly and secure even though I explicitly told it to not use those flags.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

This is PHP 7.1

The site is being accessed over https if that matters.

EDIT:
We are using Strict-Transport-Security headers on the .htaccess file. I tried commenting it out but it didn't seem to have any effect.

EDIT2:
I was able to work around this by just setting the cookie in javascript. This was preventing me from reading the cookie javascript which is where I needed it. This domain is in the HSTS preload list so I'm having a feeling that chrome is adding this flags because it knows this domain is secure. I'm not sure why it allows javascript to set them unmodified.

Does anyone have any information on HSTS preload and its effect, if any on the `set-cookie` header?

Comment: What are you trying to do with an unsecure cookie on a HSTS site? That's basically a contradiction, after the first visit at least.

Comment: Because I need to check the cookie in javascript and you cannot read the cookie in scripting languages if the cookie is HTTP only. The Its nothing security related its just an indicator that the user had previously performed a function. I supposed it could be handled differently but it really doesnt matter and isnt worth the extra effort. I would rather know thats how this works or what the problem is.

Comment: Yep, I understand for the "HTTP only" flag; it's the "secure" one that's bothering me. Anyway, have you tried to change the `session.cookie_httponly` configuration option? Maybe it's taking precedence, for some reason.

Comment: I have this problem in PHP 8.3 and it appeared right after I turn HSTS on. So I guess it could be the cause!

Answer (score 0):

I think what is interesting is there is no space around the semi-colons for the last two flags. This suggests one of three reasons:

1. This is an unimportant typo that you made when creating the questions.
2. PHP is just weird. I don’t use it so not out the realm of possibilities.
3. Something else other than PHP is setting these attributes.

[I created a way of forcing these flags in Apache even if the backend process creating the cookies didn’t set them](https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/secure-cookies/) with this Apache config:

```
# Rewrite any session cookies to make them more secure
# Make ALL cookies created by this server are HttpOnly and Secure
# (except the SPECIAL-CLIENT cookie and OTHER-COOKIE which can't be HttpOnly and is already set to Secure)  
Header edit Set-Cookie ^((?!(SPECIAL-CLIENT|OTHER-COOKIE).*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
#Strip off double Secure or HttpOnly settings as if App and Apache sets above you can sometimes get both
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*);\s?Secure;?\s?(.*);\s?Secure;?\s?(.*)$ "$1; $2; $3; Secure"
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*);\s?HttpOnly;?\s?(.*);\s?HttpOnly;?\s?(.*)$ "$1; $2; $3; HttpOnly"
#Strip off double ;; settings
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*);\s?;\s?(.*)$ "$1; $2"
```

Is it possible you are using something like this or similar to set these attributes outside of PHP?

Comment: Unless apache is doing it unbeknownst to me I doubt it. I feel like chrome is doing it. I haven't checked the headers in curl yet but that's going to be my next test when I have time. (chrome because of HSTS preload)

Comment: PS, that is not a typo, thats exactly how it came from the chrome inspector.

Comment: Yeah curl will prove it but I really doubt it’s Chrome. Check your Apache config to see if someone added something similar to above.